Lebesgue integration over non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
Volume and Integral by W. W. Rogosinski states the following regarding Lebesgue integration (he uses the abbreviation “L-integral”, and some of the notation is kind of outdated):

Let $E$ be a set in a given space $\mathsf{E} = \mathsf{E}_{n}$ of $n$ dimensions; and let, first, $y = f(P) = f(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n)$ be a non-negative function (of $n$ real variables $x_i$) defined in $E$…Let $f^{*}(P) =$ {$f(P)$ when $P \in E$; $0$ otherwise}. This function is defined in the whole space $\mathsf{E}$. We call it the extension of $f(P)$

then

A function $f(P)$, defined in the whole space $\mathsf{E}$, is said to be measurable if the sets $[f > a]$, that is the sets where $f > a$, are measurable for every real number $a$.
A function $f(P)$, defined in $E$, is said to be measurable in $E$ if its extension $f^{*}(P)$ is measurable.

and finally

A non-negative function $f(P)$ has an L-integral over $E$ if, and only if, $f(P)$ is measurable in $E$…It should be noted that the set $E_0 = [f > 0]$ is necessarily measurable if the non-negative function $f$ has an integral over $E$. The set $E$ itself need not be measurable…on the other hand, it is $E_0$ that matters.

So, it’s pretty clear that (at least according to this exposition) $E$ need not always be measurable for the Lebesgue integral over $E$ to exist. The implication (I think) is that, for example, if $f$ is integrable over measurable set $S_1$ and $f$ is zero for all points in non-measurable set $S_2$, then the integral exists over $E = S_1 \cup S_2$ (i.e. $\int_{E}f = \int_{S_1}f$)
On the other hand, this answer says:

No, the Lebesgue integral over a nonmeasurable set is not defined. So you don’t deal with that.

But surely(?) they can’t both be right. So…what’s the resolution of this apparent contradiction?

Other expositions of the Lebesgue integral I’ve seen don’t really clarify this, as they seem to focus on the case of measurable $E$, yet don’t explicitly say anything one way or the other about integration over non-measurable $E$
It looks to me like the aforementioned SE answer is in error (and Rogosinski is correct) but I’m not quite 100% sure)


This is not a matter of one being right and the other wrong, but rather a matter of one using a different convention than the other. You've already noted that Rogosinski used notation and terminology that is out-of-date. He is using a convention that is out-of-date as well. The idea that the integral of $f$ can be defined on unmeasurable sets as long as the support of $f$ is measurable, serves little real purpose, and has since been dropped.

Surely, if $f \cdot1_E$ is measurable, which is true if $E_0$ is measurable, then the integral is defined. But usually such a function is not measurable and the integral is not defined, as stated in the answer you refer to.

I suppose it depends on how one defines “usually”. Consider any function which is positive and continuous on the measurable subset $X$ and zero elsewhere (not a particularly “unusual” scenario, I would say). Then (it seems) for any measurable $S_1 \subseteq X$, non-measurable $S_2$ such that $S_2 \cap X = \emptyset$, and $E = S_1 \cup S_2$, the integral $\int_{E} f$ is in fact defined. That is, the SE answer I linked to is somewhat incorrect for a not particularly “unusual” class of functions.
